# Node.js + express.js + passport.js : stay authenticated between server restart

Tags: node.js, express

I use passport.js to handle auth on my nodejs + express.js application. I setup a LocalStrategy to take users from mongodb

My problems is that **users have to re-authenticate when I restart my node server**. This is a problem as I am actively developing it and don't wan't to login at every restart... (+ I use node supervisor)

Here is my app setup :

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret:'something'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

And session serializing setup :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
    User.findOne({email:email}, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

I tried the solution given on a blog (removed the link as it does not exist any more) using connect-mongodb without success

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret:'something else',
    cookie: {maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24 * 30}, // 30 days
        store: MongoDBStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db
    })
}));
```

**EDIT** additional problem : only one connection should be made (use of one connexion limited mongohq free service)

**EDIT 2** solution (as an edition as I my reputation is to low to answer my question by now

Here is the solution I finally found, using mongoose initiated connection

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret:'awesome unicorns',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(
        {db:mongoose.connection.db},
        function(err){
            console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
        })
}));
```

Comment: Just FYI: that blog link redirected me to a scuzzy dating site... Don't know if it is good anymore.

Comment: Oh ok,I removed the link.

Comment: Developers make scuzzy dating sites.

Comment: I have a similar-opposite problem. Users are required to re-auth after browser is restarted. Did you have this problem?

Comment: RTFM maybe: https://github.com/expressjs/session

> By default cookie.maxAge is null, meaning no "expires" parameter is set so the cookie becomes a browser-session cookie. When the user closes the browser the cookie (and session) will be removed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There's an opensource called [**connect-mongo**](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) that does exactly what you need - persists the session data in mongodb

*usage example (with a reuse of `mongoose` opened connection) :*

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sess');
app.use(express.session({
    secret:'secret',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(
    // Following lines of code doesn't work
    // with the connect-mongo version 1.2.1(2016-06-20).
    //    {db:mongoose.connection.db},
    //    function(err){
    //        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    //   }
    {mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection}
    )        
}));
```

you can read more about it here: https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo

Comment: Arnaud, thanks, I've having the same problems. Can you be more explicit regarding the db:mongoose.connection.db? I'm unsure what that means.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response, I am travelling back from Mexico to France, I will be more available in 48h. Response : Well, you must pass the mongo connection instance to connect-mongodb after it has been initialized by mongoose. mongoose.connection.db is the instance we are talking about, we pass it to connectdb through the "db" attribute.

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/LostAndFound/blob/master/LostAndFound.js)

Note that it's an old code that way need to be adapted to new APIs.

Comment: `{db:mongoose.connection.db}` **does not work**. You can use `{mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection}` which does actually work

Answer (score 6):

i use connect-mongo like so:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

var sess_conf = {
  db: {
    db: mydb,
    host: localhost,
    collection: 'usersessions' // optional, default: sessions
  },
  secret: 'ioudrhgowiehgio'
};

 app.use(express.session({
    secret: sess_conf.secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(sess_conf.db)
  }));


[...]

// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
  // persistent login sessions (recommended).
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Thank you but I have an additional problem : I want only one connection on my data base as I use mongohq free service (one connection only).

Comment: Ok here is the final, clean solution using connect-mongodb and reusing mongoose connection

Answer (score 5):

This is because you use MemoryStore (default) for sessions. Look at this code from memory.js (part of Connect framework):

```
var MemoryStore = module.exports = function MemoryStore() {
  this.sessions = {};
};
```

and this snippet from session.js (Express)

```
function session(options){
    /* some code */
    , store = options.store || new MemoryStore
    /* some code */
}
```

Now you should understand that every server restart resets the MemoryStore. In order to keep the data you have to use some other session store. You can even write your own (shouldn't be too difficult), although Redis (see [this library](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis)) might be a good choice (and it is well supported by Express).

**// EDIT**

According to [the Connect documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html) it is enough for you if you implement `get`, `set` and `destroy` methods. The following code should work:

```
customStore = {
    get : function(sid, callback) {
        // custom code, for example calling MongoDb
    },
    set : function(sid, session, callback) {
        // custom code
    },
    destroy : function(sid, callback) {
        // custom code
    }
}    

app.use(express.session({
    store: customStore
}));
```

You just need to implement calling MongoDb (or any other Db although I still recommend using nonpermament one like Redis) for storing session data. Also read the source code of other implementations to grab the idea.

Comment: Thank you. As you can see, I've tried using connect-mongodb (and connect-mongo) without success, the sessions aren't saved in my db.

Comment: @ArnaudRinquin Sorry, somehow I didn't see that. :) I've updated the answer. I am not familiar with neither connect-mongodb nor connect-mongo (I'm using mongoose with Redis as a session store) so the only advice I have for you is this: try implementing the session store yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I've found the solution few minutes ago and saw your response as I wanted to post the solution.

Comment: @ArnaudRinquin You know that you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted? Because to be honest my answer is of little help. :)

Comment: I know but my reputation was too low. I'll do it as soon as possible. Thank you for your honesty.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably obvious to experienced node users but it caught me out:

You need to configure the node session  - e.g.

```
app.use(session({secret: "this_is_secret", store: ...}));
```

***before*** initializing the passport session - e.g.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

If you call passport.session() first it won't work (and it won't warn you). I thought the problem was with the serialize/deserialize user functions and wasted hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mongoose, I tried the code presented in the answers above and it didn't work for me. I got this error when I did:

```
Error: db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times
```

However, this works for me:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret:'secret',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection:mongoose.connection})
}))
```

Note: If you don't have MongoStore for whatever reason, you need to do:

```
npm install connect-mongo --save
```

then:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing:

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(expressSession);
...
app.use(expressSession({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    key: config.session.key,
    secret: config.session.secret,
    store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        host: config.db.host,
        port: config.db.port,
        prefix: 'my-app_',
        disableTTL: true
    })
}));
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the store you are using for your sessions. The default one 'MemoryStore' does not continue to store the session when you're application stops. Check out express-session on github to find out more about what other stores there are like the mongo one. (Can't remember the name)