# Passport session over 2 servers

Tags: node.js, passport.js

My web application production deployment is on 2 servers behind a load-balancer.

I'm using passport (local strategy) with session for authentication.

When the application runs on one server everything works fine, but in production one server doesn't recognize the cookie/session established by the other server (Each request gets randomally sent to a different server, I can't control it).

As a result - i'm redirected to the login page when attempting to access pages that require authentication (even after i login).

**How can i get the two servers to create a session cookie that they both recognize** (obviously i used the same secret for the express session middleware).

Thanks,

Alon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Configure the load-balancer to always route the same ip to the same machine. Might be problematic for users who change network.

**Option two**

Use a third machine running the database and set up express.session (and any other database connections for that matter) to use that machine as store. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164312/node-js-express-js-passport-js-stay-authenticated-between-server-restart) mentions how to do it with mongoose/mongodb.

I think this is the more common solution but is of course more expensive if you don't need a third machine.

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 is not possible for me (can't control the load-balancer). I used option 2 - saving sessions in DB.