# How to add "Remember Me" to my app with passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I need a "Remember Me" checkbox when logging in like [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3-mongoose-rememberme) .
And I add a middleware before using passport

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login') {
    if (req.body.rememberme) {
      req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
    } else {
      req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
  }
  next();
});
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I can not login when `req.body.rememberme` is true and the user is remembered when `req.body.rememberme` is false.
I also tried connect-ensure-login and it still wrong.

and another question: when should I delete the cookies in my database and how?

:)

Other code is exactly the same as the passport guide

route:

```
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/user/home');
});
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/user/home');
});
```

sessions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var CreateAccessToken = function() {
    var token = user.GenerateSalt();
    User.findOne({
      accessToken: token
    }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (existingUser) {
        CreateAccessToken();
      } else {
        user.set('accessToken', token);
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err)
            return done(err);
          return done(null, user.get('accessToken'));
        })
      }
    });
  };
  if (user._id)
    CreateAccessToken();
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(token, done) {
  User.findOne({
    accessToken: token
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    return done(err, user);
  });
});
```

and the strategie:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(userId, password, done) {
  User.findOne().or([{
    username: userId
  }, {
    email: userId
  }]).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: 'Invalid password or username'
      });
    }
    if (user.Authenticate(password)) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: 'Invalid password or username'
      });
    }
  });
}));
```

---

I noticed that Express will update the cookie only when hash value changed. so I have modified the code in the middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login') {
    if (req.body.rememberme) {
      req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
      req.session._garbage = Date();
      req.session.touch();
    } else {
      req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

now I can login with "Remember Me", but it only works on chromium and firefox on Ubuntu. I still can not login with the "Remember Me" checkbox on chrome and firefox on Win7 and Android.

I checked response header when POST to "/login" on chrome on win7 and it had the same "Set-Cookie" field as it on Ubuntu, why it can not work?

---

Time is out of sync...so I post a extra time field.

```
$('#login').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, option) {
    arr.push({
      name: '__time',
      value: (new Date()).toGMTString()
    });
  }
});
```

and the "RememberMe" middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login') {
    if (req.body.rememberme) {
      req.session.cookie.maxAge = moment(req.body.__time).add('m', 3) - moment();
      req.session._garbage = Date();
      req.session.touch();
    } else {
      req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: isnt this sementically wrong? If `rememberme == true` it means the cookie should not expire? You should post more code as you need more than these three middlewares

Comment: If `rememberme == true` the cookie gets an expiry (of 3 minutes in this case), otherwise the cookie is made to be a session cookie (expiring when the browser session is done). But I agree: more code is needed.

Comment: this code is very confusing. You should separate the concerns. The `serialize` and `deserialize` functions are ony for getting a user by its id (use the database id) and serializing to a session cookie (the id wont be there in clear text if you worry). Dont mix in some doubtful security code

Comment: @pfried I am not very clear how passport-local works, like their guide  I made a unique token in `serialize` and find the user got the token in `deserialize` but I am not clear when these functions will be invoked

Comment: I had been working on this too, recently, and this was a bit helpful to me: [Node.js + express.js + passport.js : stay authenticated between server restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164312/node-js-express-js-passport-js-stay-authenticated-between-server-restart)

Answer (score 37):

I had exactly the same problem as you. The following code works for me:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local',
    { failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true }), function(req, res) {
        if (req.body.remember) {
          req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Cookie expires after 30 days
        } else {
          req.session.cookie.expires = false; // Cookie expires at end of session
        }
      res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: I've edited the example time from 3 minutes (which is less than most sessions) to 30 days. I was thinking that 3 minutes was the non-remember me mode, and `...expires = false;` meant never expire.

Comment: @rjmunro why do you redirect to '/'? is that the root path or 'login/'

Comment: That's not my code - I just added some comments, but it looks like it redirects to the root of the site once you are logged in. This answer was written a while ago :-).

Comment: This is not ideal for security reasons. There should be a new token generated each time. See the other answer with passport-remember-me

Answer (score 6):

There is now a Passport strategy for adding Remember Me functionality writen by Jared Hanson.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me

This works by issuing a unique remember-me token during every session that is consumed at the start of the next (invalidating it for future use.) As a result, this is likely to be a more secure solution.

Comment: If your app is koa.js app, https://github.com/clthck/passport-remember-me worked fine for me. It is actually a fork of jaredhanson's original repo and it just adds a support for koa.js app (along with [koa-passport](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport))

Comment: It's also worth noting that for true 'Remember Me' -- you'll need some kind of long-term persistence for the tokens, either in a cache or a database -- otherwise the server would be storing them in memory. You want to be able to restart the server and still have the remember me token be valid

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that `app.use(express.bodyParser())` is placed above your middleware, as you are relying on `req.body.rememberme`